# 404 attack with non existent URLs

Tags: google-search, url, 404, crawl-errors

Today I checked my google search console and found few interesting 404.
All those pages never existed on my site. Funny thing is that it didn't scan for some vulnerable php files. It looked like some angry person is trying to send me a message. Those messages were in my language, so posting them wont make any sense to you. First he did some testing like:

```
www.website.com/attempt-1/
www.website.com/attempt-2/
www.website.com/attempt-3-some-text/
```

That somehow worked for him, so next step was:

```
www.website.com/some-angry-text-five-words/
```

and that text was with a lot of grammar mistakes, like it would be typed by angry crazy person :)

Google search console says that those 404 links were found on:

```
website.com/
www.website.com/
website.com/findings/
```

There's no such page as /findings/ on my site.
I double checked database just to make sure it wasn't sqlinjected with a link. But found nothing.

I use smarty on my site, maybe that's how he managed to trick google?

Comment: What is "smarty"?

Comment: Smarty = PHP template engine

Answer (score 1):

Someone or something(bot) is just trying to meddle around, it is no concern for you when it comes to SEO - it will not hurt your rankings in anyway.

Check this Google+ post: [https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/RMjFPCSs5fm](https://web.archive.org/web/20170228143402/https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/RMjFPCSs5fm)

Comment: I'm not worried about SEO. Just curious how they manage to trick google into thinking that one of my pages contains link to something that doesn't exist. Or even worse, he tricked google to find non existing link on non existing page to non existing page :)

Comment: ya, people can also fiddle around with Google Analytics!

Comment: I'm personally not sure on how they did it but if you think it affects SEO use [this tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en) to take the link off google while you deal with this issue.